# vt-x is enableed, but isn't recognized

Tags: virtualization

I want to use an Android emulator like Nox or Bluestacks to play the mobile PUBG on PC. I am aware that enable virtualization in BIOS makes performance much, much better. I have an HP Omen desktop (RX580 4gb, 7th gen i5, 12gb DDR4, 128GB SSD+1TB HDD). The BIOS looks like this. I went into the Security tab and enabled vt-x, saved, and restarted. However, vt-x isn't being recognized by anything. I have Windows 10 Home, so there is no Hyper-V to disable, nor do I have any antivirus software installed (other than Windows Defender). Do you have any tips as to what I can do so virtualization works? Thanks!

also, can anyone recommend an Android emulator without sponsored apps showing up? One where you just load the .apk and can map controls? Thanks again!

Comment: "isn't being recognized by anything" Would you like to be more specific? What have you tried?

Comment: I have tried Bluestacks and Nox.